# Is explode equivalent to implode when using the same parameter?

Tags: php, explode, implode

Let's say I have the following function:

```
public function normalize($string) {
  $substrings = explode(",", $string);
  return implode(",", $substrings);
}
```

Will `($string == normalize($string))` always be true? is there any special case I should consider?

Comment: It will be the same. No special case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you have to show a problem or an issue about your question.

Comment: `$string != normalize($string)` if `$string` can't be cast to a string.

Comment: `$string != normalize($string)` if `$string` is an object that implements the `__toString()` magic method.

Comment: `$string != normalize($string)` if `$string` is a float with a [tiny floating point error](https://3v4l.org/6dPGg).

Comment: @SaidbakR This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @AlexHowansky It is equal, tried it, works because for $object with __toStrring, $object == $object . ''

Comment: @SinistraD Dang, you're right, I must have inadvertently had a `===` in my test code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $string is a string, yes.

Otherwise type conversion may occur:

```
implode(",", explode(",", 0))
```

This will result in "0" thus `$string !== normalize($string)` but `$string == normalize($string)` still holds true.